# Problems compiling Chicken Scheme egg "lookup-table"

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to **statically compile** and link a Chicken Scheme program, and this one egg is giving me some trouble. I get the same error, but with more information, when I try it at the repl; so here goes:

```
> chicken-install >/dev/null -retrieve lookup-table
> csi ./lookup-table/lookup-table.scm -I ./lookup-table

CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2014, The Chicken Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.9.0.1 (stability/4.9.0) (rev 8b3189b)
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
bootstrapped 2014-06-07

; loading /tmp/tempfabd.10142/lookup-table/lookup-table.scm ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/chicken.import.so ...
; including /tmp/tempfabd.10142/lookup-table/lookup-table-body.scm ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/srfi-1.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/srfi-69.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/ports.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/data-structures.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/extras.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/miscmacros.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/type-checks.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/type-errors.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/foreign.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/record-variants.import.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/miscmacros.so ...
; loading /var/lib//chicken/7/record-variants.so ...

Warning: reference to possibly unbound identifier `MAGIC-LIMIT' in:
Warning:    magic-count?

Error: module unresolved: lookup-table

           Call history:

           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#let ((port (optional732 tmp735 #f))) (if (not port) (*dict-print dict) (with-output-to-port ......
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#begin (##core#if (not port) (*dict-print dict) (with-output-to-port port (lambda () (*dict-p......
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#if (not port) (*dict-print dict) (with-output-to-port port (lambda () (*dict-print dict))))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (not port)
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (*dict-print dict)
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (with-output-to-port port (lambda () (*dict-print dict)))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (lambda () (*dict-print dict))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#lambda () (*dict-print dict))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#begin (*dict-print dict))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (*dict-print dict)
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (optional732 tmp735 #f)
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#let ((tmp739 tmp735)) (##core#if (null?740 tmp739) #f (car741 tmp739)))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#begin (##core#if (null?740 tmp739) #f (car741 tmp739)))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (##core#if (null?740 tmp739) #f (car741 tmp739))
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (null?740 tmp739)
           <syntax>             [dict-print] (car741 tmp739)     <--
```

All the other eggs I've tried have compiled fine. Can someone help me fix this issue, please? It's kinda stopping me in my tracks.

Answer (score 1):

The internet suggests problems with this egg, probably this helps (seems to work): in lookup-table-body.scm ~line 308 (in the definition of *magic-count?*) replace `MAGIC-LIMIT` with `12`:

```
(define-inline (magic-count? count) (<= count 12 #;MAGIC-LIMIT))
```

This `MAGIC-LIMIT` constant causing the problem seems to be used only once, and it's value is defined in lookup-table.setup... Good luck!

Comment: I kinda need it to work without actually changing the sources. Perhaps if I pass the `opts` from lookup-table.setup to `csc` when compiling? That might suffice. Why they couldn't just define `MAGIC-LIMIT` in the damn source, I have no idea.

Comment: It seems the author did not touch this egg since 2009... Why is that you don't want to change the sources, do you want to keep the compilation process automatic?

Comment: csc -unit lookup-table -emit-import-library lookup-table  -prelude "\"(define-constant MAGIC-LIMIT 12)\"" -cJ lookup-table.scm seems to work...

Comment: Yes, I want it to be automatic. I say "compile my source", and it recursively obtains the necessary eggs, determines their dependencies, and compiles everything into a single statically-linked executable. That commandline may work, but it's not something that can be automatically determined. Interrogating the .setup file seems to be a dead end, as [a] it won't always contain a declaration of `opts`, and [b] it will not `(load)`. So I can't pull anything meaningful from it at runtime.

Comment: I need to know what `chicken-install` does re the .setup file. How does it know what options to use when compiling it? Must be something to do with `setup-shared-extension-module`, but given that `(load`ing the .setup file throws a bunch of errors.....

Comment: Hm. If I `(define (verify-extension-name . args) #f)` and `(define (setup-shared-extension-module . args) (print args))`, then `(eval (read-file "lookup-table.setup"))`, I get the **expanded** args to `setup-shared-extension-module`. To wit, `lookup-table 1.13.5 inline?: #t types?: #t compile-options: (-scrutinize -prelude "(define-constant MAGIC-LIMIT 12)" -disable-interrupts -fixnum-arithmetic -local -inline-limit 50 -no-procedure-checks -optimize-level 3 -debug-level 1`. This seems promising! ;)

Comment: I deeply apreciate your patience! Unfortunately I never used chicken intensively; it looks like the chicken-install compilation does just this: '/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"lookup-table\" \"1.13.5\"))" 'lookup-table.setup' -- and this seems to spawn the proper compilation process...

Comment: Oddly, if I define `verify-extension-name` and `standard-extension` and then `eval` the contents of the .setup file.... if I do this at the repl, it works fine; but if I do it inside a [code file](http://pastebin.com/Vk3qe3Rn) it complains that these functions are not defined. What!? It seems to be because the functions are being defined *inside* my function. How do I make `eval` evaluate the code in the context of the current environment where the `eval` call resides?

Comment: but what is wrong with this csi -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"lookup-table\" \"1.13.5\"))" lookup-table.setup  ?

Comment: Produces .so files, not .o files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120936/discussion-between-dercz-and-sod-almighty).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple bug in a particular egg.  If you want this fixed, I'd suggest filing a bug report.  The most common ways to do that are to use a bug tracker (in this case, probably [bugs.call-cc.org](http://bugs.call-cc.org)), send the egg's author an e-mail or use the `chicken-users` mailing list.

PS: Regarding `chicken-users`, you'll probably have better luck getting your questions answered there than on Stack Overflow, in general.